# Keyring apparently not installed correctly with pip macos

Tags: python

I want to use the Python package keyring to avoid exposing passwords in my Python scripts. According to what I've read, all you need to do is pip install keyring and then start storing and retrieving credentials. I've done this on both my Mac laptop (Big Sur) and a CentOS 7 box. On my Mac, pip list shows that version 23.1.0 of keyring is installed, and the command line utility is available. However, when I try to set a password using the command line or in python using keyring.set_password(...) I get the following error:

File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyring/backends/macOS/**init**.py", line 38, in set_password
api.set_generic_password(self.keychain, service, username, password)
NameError: name 'api' is not defined

Line 12 of the **init**.py is a simple import of the api module:

```
    from . import api
```

and then line 38, where the error is reported, tries to set the password:

```
    api.set_generic_password(self.keychain, service, username, password)
```

Why am I getting this error? I read somewhere that you shouldn't install keyring in a venv with pip but I'm not certain why not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Error was introduced with version `keyring==23.1.0` (Aug 15, 2021)

Once I downgraded to `keyring==23.0.1` (March 25, 2021), the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the six package by typing this in the command prompt/terminal:

```
pip install six
```

Somehow, the keyring package isn't installed properly on MacOS. See [here](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/268).

Comment: The latest version is 23.1.0 and that's what was installed by pip by default.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen the article about installing six. But six was already installed. I tried reinstalling that as well but it didn't help either. However,  I am getting the same error as the one shown in the referenced article.

Comment: Is the six package on the latest version? If not, do this: pip install six==1.16.0

Comment: Yes, I have version 1.16.0 installed.  Thanks.

Comment: (I for got to add that installing six v. 1.16.0 did not solve the issue for me. It still cannot find the api module.)

Comment: Can you tell me your python version?

Comment: I tried what User One suggested and received this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring.backends' . Does that mean the problem I'm having is that it can't find a keyring module that is supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

`$ /usr/local/lib/python3.7 -c "import keyring.backends._OS_X_API"`

That should produce the underlying exception that's causing the module to be missing.

EDIT:

Try adding this

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':    # It's a solution for Mac
    import keyring.backends.OS_X
    keyring.set_keyring(keyring.backends.OS_X.Keyring())
else:   # It's a solution for Windows
    import keyring.backends.Windows
    keyring.set_keyring(keyring.backends.Windows.WinVaultKeyring())
```

Comment: The error message I got back was that the module keyring.backends could not be found.  Is that the underlying cause that you mean? Yet when I drill down through site-packages within the venv I eventaully do see keyring/backends.